# croire/trouver que vs croire/trouver sans que

Tags: grammaire, usage

> Je crois/trouve que cette solution est parfaite.
>
> Je crois/trouve cette solution parfaite.

Les deux phrases (celles avec crois et celles avec trouve) ont-elles le même sens ?
La seconde (sans que) est-elle courante ou non ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les sens sont quasiment identiques. Avec *croire*, il subsiste un léger doute tandis qu'avec *trouver*, on exprime son opinion.

La deuxième forme, sans *que*, est plus littéraire. Elle est courante avec *trouve* mais beaucoup plus rare avec *croire*.

Answer (score 2):

J'approuve jlliagre pour la nuance de sens entre croire et trouver. Bien qu'un de mes anciens prof avait l'habitude de dire devant ce genre de question : "On ne peux croire qu'en Dieu !". Croire est une intime conviction proche de la certitude objective. Trouver indique qu'il s'agit d'une opinion subjective.

Quand à la nuance entre "trouver la solution parfaite" et "trouver que la solution est parfaite". Je trouve la première plus littéraire et je crois que la seconde et plus courante.

Answer (score 2):

Je pense que c'est un peu fort de dire que c'est "quasiment identique". Les sens sont assez proches mais il y a quand même des différences qu'on peut pas ignorer.

**Croire** (dans ce sens) exprimer un avis sur un sujet qui est soit vrai soit faux. Il y a (probablement) une solution correcte. Croire exprime un avis sur une vérité.

> Je crois que le résultat est 5.
>
> Je crois qu'il y a une meilleure solution, on devrait continuer à chercher.

**Trouver** implique que c'est entièrement subjectif, dépend des préférences et des goûts de chacun, et qu'il n'y a pas de réponse correcte dans l'absolu. Trouver exprime une opinion.

> Je trouve que le rouge, ça te va bien
>
> Je trouve que ce nom sonne bien, si ça vous va on peut utiliser ça.

On ne peut pas dire :

> *Je crois que le rouge, ça te va bien*
>
> *Je trouve que le résultat est 5*

Donc pour ta solution, si c'est un truc objectif et qu'il y a une meilleure solution **objectivement** (un itinéraire plus court, une méthode qui optimise les résultat, ...), tu devrais utiliser **croire**, mais si c'est juste la meilleure solution **subjectivement** (la couleur d'un logo, un slogan, ...), tu devrais plutôt utiliser **trouver**.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse. Concernant les structure avec que ou sans que (Je trouve la solution impeccable/ je trouve que la solution est impeccable) pensez-vous qu'il y a une difference ? La version sans que est-elle courante ?

Comment: Il n'y a pas de différence de sens, mais je suis d'accord que la version sans *que* est plus littéraire et plus rare à l'oral.

Comment: Merci encore. Je voudrais pouvoir accepter toutes les réponses mais malheureusement je ne peux pas.